# Best way to run Redis/Rejson with HA on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, redis, redislabs, redisjson

As AWS & GCP is not providing managed service for any of the modules of Redis. I am looking forward to running `Redis ReJson` with HA configuration on AWS.

Is it best way to set it up on EC2 with RDB backup? How EBS storage will work as i want multi AZ also auto failover.

Right now somewhere i am planning for deploy it on Kubernetes with helm chart : https://hub.helm.sh/charts/stable/redis-ha

Which one will be better option to deploy EC2 or Kubernetes ? & How data replication will work in multi-AZ if deployed using EC2 or Kubernetes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RedisLabs provides a managed Redis with modules support on both AWS and GCP.

See: Cloud PRO https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise-cloud/